# Access PRIVATE S3 bucket from Athena in a separate AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I am able to have cross-account access on a public S3 bucket *bucketA*.
However, I need the Athena service and boto3 library to access the same S3 *bucketA* which is now a private resource.

How can it be done ?

Regards,
Aarushi

Answer (score 2):

When Amazon Athena runs queries, it uses the **current user's access permissions** to access Amazon S3.

Therefore, if you want a particular user to run Athena queries against data in S3, simply make sure that this user has access to the relevant Amazon S3 buckets.

Let's say you have:

- An IAM User (`User-A`) in Account-A
- An Amazon S3 Bucket (`Bucket-B`) in Account-B
- You want to permit `User-A` to run Amazon Athen queries against data in `Bucket-B`

You should:

- Add an **IAM policy** to `User-A` that permits them to access `Bucket-B` (presumably `s3:ListBucket` and `s3:GetObject`, at a minimum)
- Add a **Bucket Policy** to `Bucket-B` that permits access by `User-A` (this is required for cross-account access) -- the permissions should be the same as the IAM Policy (eg `s3:ListBucket` and `s3:GetObject` at a minimum)

That should allow `User-A` to run queries on data in `Bucket-B`.

See the documentation: [Cross-account Access in Athena to Amazon S3 Buckets - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cross-account-permissions.html)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to access files within a private bucket. Are IAM policy settings sufficient or any other setting is required

Comment: As above... An IAM Policy is required to grant the user access to the data in Amazon S3. Additionally, if the bucket is in a different AWS Account, then that bucket requires a Bucket Policy that grants that same IAM User permission to access the data.